# IPv6 delegated LAN prefix length - Inconsistency in RIPE NCC assignment policy

Tags: networking, home-networking, ipv6, prefix

As far as i know it is *recommended* that an ISP delegates a 56 bit IPv6 prefix (`/56`, previously `/48`), so that the host can subnet the interfaces on its LAN links.

[RFC 7368 - IPv6 Home Networking - 3.4.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7368#section-3.4.1):

> For a typical IPv6 homenet, it is not recommended that an ISP offers less than a /60 prefix, and it is highly preferable that the ISP offers at least a /56.

When it comes to *Best Practices* RIPE NCC agrees with this...

[Best Current Operational Practice for Operators - 4.2.3.](https://www.ripe.net/publications/docs/ripe-690#4-2--prefix-assignment-options)

> It is strongly discouraged to assign prefixes longer than /56 unless there are very strong and unsolvable technical reasons for doing this.

So far so good... But as far as i understand the OFFICIAL [`IPv6 Address Allocation and Assignment Policy`](https://www.ripe.net/publications/docs/ripe-681#assignment_size) violates the best pratices (Section 5.4.1.):

> End Users are assigned an End Site assignment from their LIR or ISP. The size of the assignment is a local decision for the LIR or ISP to make, using a minimum value of a /64 (only one subnet is anticipated for the End Site).

Of course i read the whole policy and might have overlooked something. As far as i know there is no differentiation between the prefix for the WAN and LAN side but because the document is about *address assignment policy* i would suggest that it only makes sense to police delegated prefixes.

#### So why does the RIPE NCC *Policy* specify a minimum of /64 when /56 is recommended and longer prefixes are discouraged?

Comment: Is this just a philosophical question of why allow a minimum that's lower than a strongly encouraged "best practice"? I think it's just humility on the part of the standards bodies that they don't know the constraints of the ISPs, so they're not going to dictate /56 even though it's a very good idea. /64 is the absolute minimum for a single LAN because of how the addressing system works.

Comment: *Is this just a philosophical question...?* No, and i don't think there is a philosophical reason behind a technical policy rather then a technical reason, therefor a rational. I strongly suggested that i misunderstood something, which is usually the case, therefore i'd asked... Thanks to you, at least i know that there is no misunderstanding.